# Django / Factoryboy - unable to delete instances in test

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I am writings tests for a django application and I've run into a problem were deleted objects still exist in the test database after I've supposedly deleted them.

I'm using the following factory

```
class CMSPageFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = CMSPage

    title = factory.Faker('company')
    tenant = factory.SubFactory(TenantFactory)
    key = factory.Faker('slug')
    protected = False
    in_navigation = False
    active = True
```

This is the test I am running

```
def test_example_for_so(self):
  page = CMSPageFactory()
  page.delete()
  self.assertFalse(page)
```

And it raises the following error:
`AssertionError: <CMSPage: Fletcher LLC> is not false`

I must be missing something very obvious but for the life of me I cannot figure out what. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't create the object because you're not using `.create()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure, `page` still exists in the db?

Calling `delete()` on a django model instance (which your factory supposedly creates) *will* delete the database row, but nor your local python representation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete

> Issues an SQL DELETE for the object. This only deletes the object in the database; the Python instance will still exist and will still have data in its fields.

Comment: @Jasper to actually make sure no db rows are present, you could try:
`assert CMSPage.objects.count() == 0`

Answer (score 2):

The object was deleted from the database but still exists in memory. From the [Model delete docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete):

> Issues an SQL DELETE for the object. This only deletes the object in
>   the database; the Python instance will still exist and will still have
>   data in its fields. This method returns the number of objects deleted
>   and a dictionary with the number of deletions per object type

What you can do in the test is get the id and then try to get the object from the database, or count the objects in the database and expect 0.